How do I rotate a uv texture on a sphere without tilting it?
I'm trying to change the direction of the front face of the uv texture on a sphere, but in the process I'm somehow "tilting" the textures, and I don't know why. I'd like them to not be tilted.
Ideally, the textures/spheres would be able to point in any direction and always have the top of the texture face upward, kind of like how a player's camera in a game always has a level horizon.
I believe the "v" component of the uv texture should vary along the longitude lines of the sphere if its pole were fixed toward the z-axis (global up direction).
Viewed from (10, -10, 10), this is how it looks with the textures not rotated at all, pointing straight forward. Generated by setting roll, pitch, and yaw values to 0.

Viewed from (10, -10, 10), this is how it looks after my current (flawed) rotation method, pitching and yawing it positive 45 degrees with 0 roll but with the unintended side effect of making everything "tilted" to the left by 45 degrees or so.
Note how Saul Goodman's head and the graph are both cocked to the side.

Notably, it doesn't have the "tilting" issue if the image is exclusively rotated by pitch OR yaw, only if it's rotated by both.
Here's the (flawed) code I'm using to make this transformation. I might eventually convert it to shader code.

pub fn get_unit_sphere_uv(intersection_point: Point3) -> (Float, Float) {
    // Pitch and yaw will be parameterized later, and likely calculated from
    // a face_direction vector that points where the texture should face.
    // but that is not my main concern right now
    let roll = 0.0;       // I have NO roll set.
    let pitch = PI / 4.0; // equivalent to 45 degrees
    let yaw = PI / 4.0;   // equivalent to 45 degrees
    let rotation_matrix = nalgebra::Rotation3::from_euler_angles(roll, pitch, yaw);

    let rotated_point = rotation_matrix * intersection_point;
    
    let (theta, phi) = get_unit_sphere_angles(rotated_point);
    let u = phi / TAU;
    let v = theta / PI;
    (u, v)
}

// This is probably ok since the textures work when not rotated, but showing it just in case
fn get_unit_sphere_angles(intersection_point: Point3) -> (Float, Float) {
    let theta = (-intersection_point.z).acos();
    let phi = Float::atan2(intersection_point.y, intersection_point.x) + PI;
    (theta, phi)
}



I don't understand the question. If you don't want the texture to be rotated, just don't rotate them. Can you show us an image of the result you want?

Essentially what I want is for Saul Goodman's head to not be cocked sideways and for the graph-ball's y-axis to be pointing straight up inside of being 45 degrees to the side as it is. Currently, for the graph, it goes "+" -> "x" when i want "+" -> "+"
I'm not very good at drawing but I added my attempt to illustrate what I want.

Ok I figured out how to do it. Still not sure why this works, but I had to make the rotation matrix by multiplying two separate rotation matrices, each made with only one component of the overall rotation.
pub fn get_unit_sphere_uv(intersection_point: Point3) -> (Float, Float) {
    let roll = 0.0;
    let pitch = PI / 4.0; // equivalent to 45 degrees
    let yaw = PI / 4.0;   // equivalent to 45 degrees
    let rotation_matrix = nalgebra::Rotation3::from_euler_angles(0.0, pitch, 0.0)
        * nalgebra::Rotation3::from_euler_angles(0.0, 0.0, yaw);

    let rotated_point = rotation_matrix * intersection_point;
    
    let (theta, phi) = get_unit_sphere_angles(rotated_point);
    let u = phi / TAU;
    let v = theta / PI;
    (u, v)
}

For the confused commenters, this is what I wanted:


Ah, I see. Yes, I was missing something, just for education try swapping both matrices and see what you get then. If I'm not mistaken you should get the first result in that case.

Tested it, you're right (still not sure why though).

I think pitch is not in the direction you think it is. Try each rotation on it's own.
